# Rails Development Productivity - Top Textmate Shortcuts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I want to improve my Rails coding productivity using Textmate.  Obviously, shortcuts (whether native to Textmate or to the Mac) can greatly assist.  What shortcuts give you the greatest bang for your dev buck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> Define a new method.

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> Comment out current line.

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Go to file

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Go to line

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> Shift text left

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> Shift text right

Answer (score 1):

I have found this useful
http://pragmaticstudio.com/rails/RailsTextMateCheats.pdf